# Is it possible to "mask out" unwanted inputs and feature maps in PyTorch so that PyTorch simply ignores them?

Tags: computer-vision, pytorch, object-detection

Recently, I've been playing around with PyTorch and I'm curious if it's possible to modify a Fully Convolutional Network so that it operates on a nonrectangular region of an image **only**.

Let's take [an arbitrary image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8cIHH.png). Within this image, there is a non-rectangular region of pixels that I already know that I am interested in (the blue region of [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8cIHH.png), where each square is conveniently the size of the kernel). Is there a way for me to tell a network to only operate on the blue region and not bother with the rest of the image (yellow region)?

I know I can just turn the unwanted part of the image to zeroes, but that seems like a waste; the network will still slide a convolutional kernel over the zeroed-out part of the image uselessly. **Is it possible to provide a mask or something to tell PyTorch** "don't bother sliding the conv operator over this region of the image; everything downstream is automatically 0"?

I've read about geometric neural networks for graph inputs and such, but in my head, it seems a bit overkill for this idea.

Comment: I don't think that's possible. Also, it's difficult to generalize...I mean such regions would be different in all images.

Comment: @snowdenassange Yeah I know the regions would be different for all images, but I figured since the learned parameters are just the kernel values anyway, then it shouldn't be too difficult to train the network on images like normal, but then do inference on parts of the image only

Answer (score 0):

It should possible to ignore them using partial convolutions. For that you need to define those regions you want to ignore as invalid pixels.